# About scope in Ruby local and instance/class variables?

Tags: ruby, class, variables, scope, instance

I have a script for a simulation I'm working on:

```
  def winner_client
    clients = [@client1, @client2, @client3]
    @winner = clients.find { |drunkest| drunkest.drunk == 3 }.name
    puts "#{@winner} is too drunk!"
    Bouncer.kick(@winner)
  end
end
```

In the `winner_client` method, I want the `clients` array to work at the class level so I can use it in other methods. But if I do this:

```
class OpenBar
  @@clients = [@client1, @client2, @client3]

  def initialize
   #...
```

when I call the `winner_client` method it raises

```
KatzBar.rb:57:in block in winner_client': undefined method drunk' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: There are two problems here: 1. You're initializing `@@clients` at the same time you're defining the class, which is long before you've given `@client1` et al a value, ergo `nil`; and 2. `@client1` in the class context is not the same variable as `@client1` in the instance method context. You need to assign `@@clients` in an instance method after you've assigned values to `@client1` et al.

Comment: @Jordan Okay, at the end of the initialize method I added the line `@@clients.push(@client1, @client2, @client3)` and it worked :) Thanks for the help! Edit: In the initialize method I give @client1, etc. their value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to define `clients` so that it's available in multiple methods, you can make it a method itself...

```
def clients
  [@client1, @client2, @client3]
end
```

This will make it available to all methods of the same instance.

If you want it available for ALL instances, that's a different problem, but still possible.  Create a class method to set and get your clients...

```
def self.clients=(array)
  @@clients = array
end

def self.clients
  @@clients
end
```

When you have a method in one instance, you can save the clients with...

```
OpenBar.clients = [@client1, @client2, @client3]
```

And in a different instance you can access it with...

```
OpenBar.clients
```